# How to enforce a range for variable when taking a limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to compute the limit of the following complex expression with respect to $\lambda$. It gives me an error which I think has to do with defining the range of the variable. In my case it is real positive number. How can I add that to the

```
Limit[1/6 (-2 k \[Lambda] - (2 I 2^(
       1/
        3) \[Lambda] (3 \[Lambda] + 
         k^2 (3 + \[Lambda])))/(-I k \[Lambda]^2 (2 k^2 (-9 + \
\[Lambda]) + 9 \[Lambda]) + 
       3 Sqrt[3]
         Sqrt[\[Lambda]^3 (4 k^6 (-1 + \[Lambda])^2 + 4 \[Lambda]^3 + 
           k^2 \[Lambda]^2 (12 + \[Lambda]) + 
           4 k^4 \[Lambda] (3 + 5 \[Lambda]))])^(1/3) + 
    I 2^(
     2/3) (-I k \[Lambda]^2 (2 k^2 (-9 + \[Lambda]) + 9 \[Lambda]) + 
       3 Sqrt[3]
         Sqrt[\[Lambda]^3 (4 k^6 (-1 + \[Lambda])^2 + 4 \[Lambda]^3 + 
           k^2 \[Lambda]^2 (12 + \[Lambda]) + 
           4 k^4 \[Lambda] (3 + 5 \[Lambda]))])^(
     1/3)), \[Lambda] -> \[Infinity]]
```

The output I get is

```
DirectedInfinity[-2 k - (
  2 I 2^(
   1/3) (3 + k^2))/(-9 I k - 2 I k^3 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 + k^2])^(
  1/3) + I 2^(2/3) (-9 I k - 2 I k^3 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 + k^2])^(1/3)]
```

Comment: That is o.k. The limit is a infinite multiple of of this complex number. Look "DirectedInfinity" up in the help.

Comment: @Daniel Huber: It would be OK if it were true, but Mathematica seems to fail to compute this limit correctly. If I am not mistaken the limit should be `-k^3`

Comment: @azerbajdzan That's what I thought. Did you compute the limit using mathemtica somehow?

Comment: This is tricky. For some ranges of `k` the "direction" of that infinity vanishes. But for others the infinity is correct. Try for example with the substitution `k -> 2 - 3*I`. `Limit` claims a particular directed infinity, and numerical experiments bear that out.

Comment: @Rudinberry: See my answer.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: This is because 2-nd and 3-rd roots are in general multi-functions. If you choose the "correct root" for each root in the expression you get `-k^3` even for `k -> 2 - 3*I`.

Comment: No. They are regular functions, and use a particular convention for branch cuts. Possibly you have in mind that they might not vary smoothly in the parameter.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Roots are mathematically multi-functions. It does not matter that Mathematica's root outputs just one of possible roots, it is limitation of math software but math itself does not have this limitation. See my updated answer.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I'm aware that roots come in sets. But it is irrelevant for this thread because the input is a function, not a bunch of simultaneous branches. That is to say, it actually does matter that e.g. `(3+5*lambda)^(1/3)` give a particular value rather than three values when`lambda` is given a numerical value.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: I agree with you if you (or OP) care only about one particular root. But I suspect that OP got his expression out of some degree three polynomial, like for example the polynomial I gave in my answer, and that he was solving some problem that in fact does not care which of the roots to take. All three roots are valid solutions to his problem. The user being relatively new to this site could thought that taking limit of one root is simpler problem than solving the problem as a whole.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: ... and also it is a matter of fact, which can be seen from my answer, that if the limit exists it must be `-k^3` and nothing else, whether you take into account only one particular root or all roots.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I am not replicating your result. Specifically I set `ee=<your expression in x>`. Then: `In[2211]:= eek = ee /. k -> 2 - 3*I;
eek /. x -> 1111.1

Out[2212]= -2416.68 + 3085.11 I

In[2210]:= -(2 - 3*I)^3

Out[2210]= 46 + 9 I` How did you show the limit was `-k^3` for this substitution?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: The limit diverges for this particular expression for `k -> 2 - 3*I`, because the expression is only one particular root of cubic. If you take limits of all three roots of my polynomial in `y` then one of them will be `-k^3` and the other two will diverge for any choice of `k`.  That is the whole point.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Solve for `y` in `y^3 + k x y^2 - (x^2 + k^2 x) y - k^3 x^2 == 0`. You get three roots. One of them will be equal to the OP expression for any choice of `x` (lambda) and `k`. Then take limit of all these three roots for particular choice of `k`. You get one limit to be equal `-k^3` and other two some infinities...

Comment: @azerbajdzan When you carry out the process you describe, you are solving a different problem. Related, yes. But different. And these sets do seem to contain the limit. But that limit is not in all cases `-k^3`; in some regions (in the space of the parameter `k`) it is actually an infinity.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: I stop the discussion, we are turning in a circle.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica can compute the limit for numeric values of `k` (with some warnings) which I used to figure out the limit.

I used `x` instead of lambda and also `Quiet` to ignore warnings.

From the output it is evident that the limit is equal `-k^3`.

Maybe Mathematica needs help by using [L'Hôpital's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) rule on the expression before computing the limit but I have not tried it.

```
Table[{k, 
    Limit[1/6 (-2 k x - (2 I 2^(1/3)
            x (3 x + k^2 (3 + x)))/(-I k x^2 (2 k^2 (-9 + x) + 9 x) + 
           3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
            x^3 (4 k^6 (-1 + x)^2 + 4 x^3 + k^2 x^2 (12 + x) + 
               4 k^4 x (3 + 5 x))])^(1/3) + 
        I 2^(2/3) (-I k x^2 (2 k^2 (-9 + x) + 9 x) + 
           3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
            x^3 (4 k^6 (-1 + x)^2 + 4 x^3 + k^2 x^2 (12 + x) + 
               4 k^4 x (3 + 5 x))])^(1/3)), 
     x -> \[Infinity]]}, {k, -5, 5}] // RootReduce // Quiet
```

---

```
{{-5,125},{-4,64},{-3,27},{-2,8},{-1,1},{0,0},{1,-1},{2,-8},{3,-27},{4,-64},{5,-125}}
```

The limit can be computed also rigorously but not the straight way.

The OP expression is root of this polynomial in `y`:

```
y^3 + k x y^2 - (x^2 + k^2 x) y - k^3 x^2 == 0
```

The limit of `y` (`y` being the root of the polynomial) as `x->∞` can be computed this way:

```
AsymptoticSolve[y^3 + k x y^2 - (x^2 + k^2 x) y - k^3 x^2 == 0, y, {x, ∞, 1}]
Limit[y /. %, x -> ∞]
```

---

$$\left\{\left\{y\to \frac{k^7+k^5}{x}-k^3\right\},\left\{y\to \frac{2 x}{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}\right\},\left\{y\to \frac{2 x}{\sqrt{k^2+4}+k}\right\}\right\}$$

$$\left\{-k^3,\frac{\infty }{\text{sgn}\left(k-\sqrt{k^2+4}\right)},\frac{\infty }{\text{sgn}\left(k+\sqrt{k^2+4}\right)}\right\}$$

So we see that one root of the polynomial always approaches `y->-k^3` as `x -> ∞`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `1/6 (-2 k \[Lambda]-(2 I 2^(1/3) \[Lambda] (3 \[Lambda]+k^2 (3+\[Lambda])))/(-I k \[Lambda]^2 (2 k^2 (-9+\[Lambda])+9 \[Lambda])+3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[\[Lambda]^3 (4 k^6 (-1+\[Lambda])^2+4 \[Lambda]^3+k^2 \[Lambda]^2 (12+\[Lambda])+4 k^4 \[Lambda] (3+5 \[Lambda]))])^(1/3)+I 2^(2/3) (-I k \[Lambda]^2 (2 k^2 (-9+\[Lambda])+9 \[Lambda])+3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[\[Lambda]^3 (4 k^6 (-1+\[Lambda])^2+4 \[Lambda]^3+k^2 \[Lambda]^2 (12+\[Lambda])+4 k^4 \[Lambda] (3+5 \[Lambda]))])^(1/3))/.{k->1,\[Lambda]->1000.000000}` results in `-166.667 + 891715. I` , not in accordance with  your speculations .

Comment: @user64494: Nope, the result is `-1`.

Comment: @user64494: Unfortunately, it is `-0.998007 - 4.54747*10^-13 I` Check your computer :-)

Comment: @three777: You are right. Sorry for the trouble,